# Change the version of node with the terminal Linux Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, nodes

I have problem with nodejs I tried to get a new version but didn't work. I deleted the old version 12.** after that I installed the new one 19.x. when I tap node -v it giving me this

[image: 1]

What can I do ?

I search for the storage capacity thinking that was the problem but it isn't !

Comment: Please edit your question to include a copy paste of the error instead of a screenshot

Comment: The screen shot you provided says the command node is not found, it means most likely the instalation failed somehow, or your `PATH` env does not include the path to the node executable, try `which node` and see if `PATH` matches the output

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install nodejs` as suggested by the error message?

Comment: take a look at this link, it will help you. https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation

Comment: I guess it is better use `NVM` if you are going to switch back and forth in `node.js`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) for installing and switching node version on Ubuntu.

**First NVM command line tool.**

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.2/install.sh | bash
```

Then

**For installing new node version.**

```
nvm install 14
```

**For switching node version.**

```
nvm use 14
```

**Done :)**

```
node -v
v14.18.0
```